# Visual Studio 2022 and creating react and ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2022, I'm trying to create a project with React and ASP.NET Core. But there is error when trying to create the project:

[image: project type screenshot]

This is the error:

[image: error screenshot]

I didn't get the ASP.NET Core with React.js template.

Comment: Have you installed node.js on your machine? In addition, its better to make them in two project, asp.net core project should be in visual studio and react project should better be in  vscode.

Comment: yes, I  installed node.js

Comment: Your error doesn't indicating that, have you tried to open the proejct in vscode?

Comment: Hows your project structure look like? Could you include your project structure in the question.

Comment: i am trying to create a project using asp.net and react but unable to create the project. i got the error. sdk not found. as i have mentioned the error image above

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't get the ASP.NET Core with React.js template

In order to get React and Asp.net core templete, you should have following prerequisite:

1. Visual studio 2022 version 17.8 at least
2. NPM installed on your machine
3. Asp.net web development package

[image]

Once you installed above requirement, you  should get this templete in visual studio search box: as following:

[image]

Now create your react app either with javascript or typescript: It should look as following:

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you still encounter any error, please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022#create-the-frontend-app)

Comment: When trying to create the solution. i got the error message " The SDK 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.271090-alpha' specofed cpuld be found D:\ReactApp\reactapp.client\reactapp.client.esproj

Comment: Make sure you have node.js version installed and the version matched with your project. In addition, you have the .NET sdk installed as well. Furthermore, you could follow the steps I followed.